# How to work with javascript promises in clojurescript?

Tags: interop, clojurescript

I have a problem with js promises:
I'm trying to convert this js code:

```
stripe.createToken(card).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the customer that there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
```

And I have the following:

```
(go
     (let [result (<!
                   (.createToken stripe @(subscribe [:card-element]))
                   )]
       (prn "result is" result)
       ;; (if (.-error result)
       ;;   (.textContent (js/document.getElementById "card-errors") (.-message .-error result))
       ;;   (prn "response is" (js/stripeTokenHandler (.-token result)))
       ;;   )
       )
    )
```

But I get "No protocol method ReadPort.take! defined for type object: [object Promise]"

How do I do the js .then() part in cljs?

Comment: I doubt switching to core.async will do you any good here.  I'd just chain the .then with an (anon) fn to mimic the js code as close as you can.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are a little bit confused with JavaScript interop. You can take a look at the [Cheatsheet](https://cljs.info/cheatsheet/) under the `JavaScript Interop` section.

Here are some quick examples:

```
JS                            CLJS

object.method(arg1, arg2) <=> (.method object arg1 arg2)
object.field              <=> (.-field object)
object.field = "foo"      <=> (set! (.-field object) "foo")
object.nested.field       <=> (.-field (.-nested object))
```

To improve readability, you can use the [`->` arrow macro](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/-%3E):

```clj
object.nested.field       <=> (-> object .-nested .-field)
```

You can then rewrite your example as:

```clj
(-> (.createToken stripe card)
    (.then (fn [result]
             (if-let [error (.-error result)]
               (-> (.getElementById js/document "card-errors")
                   (.-textContent)
                   (set! (.-message error)))
               (js/stripeTokenHandler (.-token result)))))
    ;; if there is a `catch` branch
    (.catch (fn […] …)))
```